# Tableau - convert month number to string

Tags: tableau-desktop

in order to convert an object to a string (date + nulls) I have used the following script:

```
ifnull(STR(DAY([EXTRACT]))+'/'+STR(MONTH([EXTRACT]))+'/'+STR(YEAR([EXTRACT])),'Live Connection')
```

This gives a result of 1/7/2023

What and how I can change the middle part to make the month appear as JULY ?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

```
ifnull(STR(DAY([EXTRACT]))+'/'+DATENAME('month',([EXTRACT]))+'/'+STR(YEAR([EXTRACT])),'Live Connection')
```

This is actually the answer